# Portfolio website not fitting to smaller devices

Tags: html, css

Why is the website not fitting correctly to smaller devices?
There is still a horizontal scroll bar. When entered in design view, mobile devices don't show in terms of what I want. I tried to resize everything but it still doesn't work.

Could it be margin or padding somewhere? Or the project sections too big? Or something to do with media queries?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 110px auto 1fr 470px auto auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "hero hero hero hero"
    "about about about about"
    "text text text text"
    "project1 project1 project1 project1"
    "project2 project2 project2 project2"
    "project3 project3 project3 project3"
    "project4 project4 project4 project4"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "hero"
      "about"
      "text"
      "project1"
      "project2"
      "project3"
      "project4"
      "footer";
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  section.content-container {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  footer.content-container {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50px;
  right: 60px;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 18px;
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.hero {
  grid-area: hero;
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-h1 {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.hero-h1-color {
  color: #222222;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1240px;
}

.about {
  grid-area: about;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.home-h2-text {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding: 90px 100px 80px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.home-h3-text {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 90px 100px 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.text {
  grid-area: text;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  padding-top: 138px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.text-h3-color {
  color: #222222;
}

.project1 {
  grid-area: project1;
  background-color: #fdf0f2;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.project2 {
  grid-area: project2;
  background-color: #f8f7ff;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.project3 {
  grid-area: project3;
  background-color: #fdf0f2;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.project4 {
  grid-area: project4;
  background-color: #eff5fd;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 80px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.footer-text-color {
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

    <header class="header">
      <div><a href=index.html class="name">Web Developer</a></div>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href=about.html class="nav-link">About</a>
        <a href=projects.html class="nav-link">Projects</a>
        <a href=contact.html class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>




    <div class="hero">

      <h1 class="hero-h1">ABC <br /><span class="hero-h1-color">front end developer</span></h1>




    </div>
    <section class="content-container about">

      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Nice to <br />meet you</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>


    </section>

    <div class="content-container text">
      <h3>ABCDEFG <br /><span class="text-h3-color">ABCDEFG.</span></h3>
    </div>

    <section class="content-container project1">

      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 1</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>

    </section>
    <section class="content-container project2">


      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 2</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>

    </section>
    <section class="content-container project3">

      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 3</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>


    </section>
    <section class="content-container project4">


      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 4</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>

    </section>
    <footer class="content-container footer">

      <div class="footer-text">Let's <br> <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span></div>

      <ul>

        <li><a href=about.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href=projects.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href=contact.html class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
      </ul>



    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` already in your head?

Comment: The way the page is currently used, you could likely simplify the css considerably by using flexbox. The way you're currently using the grid (see `grid-template-areas` for example) isn't really helpful, and you're using absolute positioning for the header title for some reason ? Don't get me wrong, `grid` is a good thing, but your site doesn't represent a grid at all, its just a one dimensional layout; a single column of rows (for which `display:flex` is more suited). You could make the header itself a flexbox as well consisting of 2 columns (1 for the title, 1 for the navigation)

Comment: @Kameron I didn't have the meta name viewport tags, but included them and its still the same. I want to suppress the horizontal scroll on mobile view but don't know how to do it?

Comment: @user8 See edited answer for preventing horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest your code in a flex container which is what I did. For the example, I called it `main-wrapper`. I then added some flex-box styles to that class and applied `overflow: hidden;` to make it so it doesn't scroll. Then I added some sample media queries to align your nav components when resizing. They are marked at the bottom of your CSS labeled `/* additions */` Feel free to change around as you desire, but this should get you on the right track.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 110px auto 1fr 470px auto auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "hero hero hero hero"
    "about about about about"
    "text text text text"
    "project1 project1 project1 project1"
    "project2 project2 project2 project2"
    "project3 project3 project3 project3"
    "project4 project4 project4 project4"
    "footer footer footer footer";
  justify-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "hero"
      "about"
      "text"
      "project1"
      "project2"
      "project3"
      "project4"
      "footer";
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  section.content-container {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 90vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  footer.content-container {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50px;
  right: 60px;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 18px;
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.hero {
  grid-area: hero;
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-h1 {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.hero-h1-color {
  color: #222222;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1240px;
}

.about {
  grid-area: about;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
  width: 80vw;
}

.home-h2-text {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding: 90px 100px 80px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.home-h3-text {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 90px 100px 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.text {
  grid-area: text;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  padding-top: 138px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.text-h3-color {
  color: #222222;
}

.project1 {
  grid-area: project1;
  background-color: #fdf0f2;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.project2 {
  grid-area: project2;
  background-color: #f8f7ff;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.project3 {
  grid-area: project3;
  background-color: #fdf0f2;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.project4 {
  grid-area: project4;
  background-color: #eff5fd;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 80px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: 'Khula', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.footer-text-color {
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* additions */

.main-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .logo > .name {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 35%;
  }
  
  .logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .content-container .about {
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .footer-text {
    align-items: center;
  }
}


.content-container {
  width: 80vw;
}
.footer-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="grid-container">

    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo"><a href=index.html class="name">Web Developer</a></div>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href=about.html class="nav-link">About</a>
        <a href=projects.html class="nav-link">Projects</a>
        <a href=contact.html class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>




    <div class="hero">

      <h1 class="hero-h1">ABC <br /><span class="hero-h1-color">front end developer</span></h1>




    </div>
    <section class="content-container about">

      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Nice to <br />meet you</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>


    </section>

    <div class="content-container text">
      <h3>ABCDEFG <br /><span class="text-h3-color">ABCDEFG.</span></h3>
    </div>

    <section class="content-container project1">

      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 1</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>

    </section>
    <section class="content-container project2">


      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 2</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>

    </section>
    <section class="content-container project3">

      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 3</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>


    </section>
    <section class="content-container project4">


      <h2 class="home-h2-text">Project 4</h2>

      <h3 class="home-h3-text">About Me</h3>

    </section>
    <footer class="content-container footer">

      <div class="footer-text">Let's <br> <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span></div>

      <ul>

        <li><a href=about.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href=projects.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href=contact.html class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
      </ul>



    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** prevent horizontal scroll w/ initial scroll. I kept the `main-wrapper` div I added on to add the styles too. You can use `max-width: 100%;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` to avoid horizontal scroll.

**EDIT 2** set `width: 80vw;` on about to get the same width as before.

Comment: Apologies if this is a newbie question, but how do I make the project section colour boxes the original size on desktop view. It's a lot smaller than before? And for some reason, there is horizontal scroll on desktop view. How do I suppress horizontal scroll on both mobile and desktop view?

Comment: @user8 You have no width associated with that class. You can set your width on your `.about` to `width: 80vw;`. Using dynamic widths like % or viewport are very responsive.

Comment: @user8 I thought `.about` was each colored section. Turns out you will have to add 80vw to `content-container` also

Comment: I want the about section to be the same as the project section. Apologies if my question was confusing.

Comment: I Think your second edit was better, because no on mobile view it looks different.

Comment: @user8 See the final edits I just made. I think that will work nicely for you! I added `width: 100vw` on your `section.content-container` media query you already had.

Comment: May I ask why the content container for the projects and the about different? Also when on smaller view, the margins for each colour boxes disappeared, and the footer section is to the right? Apologies if am asking to much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240355/discussion-between-kameron-and-user8).